# Android - Is there any way to place a picture behind an ListItem?

Tags: android, listview, imageview

do u guys know if there is a way to place a picture behind each Listitem?

I want to build a usual ListView with items. When I check an item - the item swipes automatically to the right - half the way (i know how to do that).

But after that there should be a picture behind that automatic swiped item on the left.

Thank u in advance! :)

Comment: I don't know specifically how to do that, but i trust you're using a RecyclerView for the list?

Comment: i work with a baseadapter. The ListView is connected to a Fragment.